# How do I enable breadcrumbs?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I have a page showing a list of *Article* nodes, where I need to display breadcrumbs as *Homepage / Tag title / Article title*, instead of *Homepage / Article title* Drupal uses by default.

I installed the *Menu Breadcrumbs* module, but I don't understand how to display its breadcrumbs. Are they shown in a block?

Comment: Yeah normally you have a breadcrumb block and on the structure > blocks page you place it in a region where you want to show it (above content, below hero, whatever). Breacrumbs usually show the nested path of a page in the main menu. Which usually is also reflected in a page's URL alias. Like https://example.com/tag/article. Does https://example.com/tag exist on your site? And do both the tage page and article page exist in your main menu? The article item being a child of the tag item? I have made very good experience with https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb.

Answer (score 3):

Breadcrumb block relies on URL aliases to build its content. To have your breacrumb display "Home > Tag title" when you are on your article page, you need your article URL alias to "include" the tag URL alias.

Example:

- In /admin/structure/block, make sure that the Breadcrumbs block is enabled and displayed in a region of your theme,
- Create a "Tag" taxomony term called "Test tag" with "/test-tag" URL alias
- Create an "Article" with "/test-tag/my-article" URL alias
- That's it! Now when you visit "/test-tag/my-article", your breadcrumb block should display "Home >> Test tag"

Now, for having your breadcrumbs block display the current page title as well (e.g. "Home >> Test tag >> My Article"), this is no default configuration and you have to rely either on custom code ([see this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/743366)) or a module (https://www.drupal.org/project/current_page_crumb for a simple solution or, as leymannx mentioned it, https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb for a more customizable solution).

Comment: @stckvrw – https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto

Comment: @leymannx is right. Pathauto is the module you need. It allows you to set URL alias patterns for your website contents and it automatically creates these URL aliases when you create/save content.